# What is the correct implementation of Katz index in python?

Tags: python, networkx, data-mining

I am trying to implement Katz index using the following formula

```
alpha=0.01

G = nx.karate_club_graph()
A=nx.adjacency_matrix(G).todense()
n=A.shape[0]
I=np.eye(n,n)
result=np.linalg.inv(iden - (alpha * A))-I
print(np.round(result,6))
```

However I am not sure if this implementation is correct, because no iteration (path length is involved). I just directly code this formula `inv((I − alpha*A)-I`

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: do you have a reference to a publication or a link to some more details of the katz-index?

Comment: have you considered using a library such as [NetworkX](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.centrality.katz_centrality.html)?

Comment: hi @boraas, yes i did, i was just wondering weather my implimentation also make sense

Answer (score 1):

I think that according to the katz metric line 5 should be:

```
result=np.linalg.inv(I - (alpha * A))-I
```

NB: In order to access the probability of link, for instance (3,4) because lists start from 0.

```
print("katz",link,"=",katz[link[0]-1,link[1]-1])
```

Answer (score 0):

NetworkX library in python uses a power method to implement the Katz index. you can compare result of your algorithm with that

Comment: Add some code to improve the answer